# What is global object UI in meteor framework and how should it be utilised?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

A console.log(UI) will produce the following result 

`Object {_DOMBackend: Object, _EventSupport: Object, _throwNextException: false, currentView: null, _globalHelpers: Object…}`

It seems there is a lack of documentation out there, would someone kindly share more information on this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not documented because it's been deprecated a while ago.

`UI` used to contain several functions that were moved to the `Template` namespace, ie `UI.registerHelper` is now `Template.registerHelper`.

You can just ignore it, as it will be eventually removed in future versions of Meteor.